# Why is my Python BZ Oregonator unable to compile?

Tags: python, ode, odeint

I am trying to simulate the colour changes within the solution of the Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction by solving ODEs and to produce a graph which will demonstrate oscillations using odeint.

I have an error message 'AxisError: axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0' and I do not know why this is happening, I am very new to Python and I am struggling.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


# Dimensionless parameters
c1 = 10
c2 = 0.15
c3 = 0.005
c4 = 0.02

#pack 3 initial conditions with state of x,y,z into y0
y0 = [1,0,0]
k = 1


def Oregonator (t,Y):
  x = Y[0]
  y = Y[1]
  z = Y[2]
 dxdt = c1 + c2*x - x - x*y**2
 dydt = (x + x*y**2 - y)/c3
 dzdt = (y-z)/c4
 return [dxdt,dydt,dzdt]


t = np.linspace(0, 10,100)

Y = odeint(y0,t,Oregonator)

plt.plot(t,Y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('other side')

plt.show()
```

I am using Spyder to process the Python code.
I appreciate any help that can be given, thank you.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the call to `odeint` to be conform with its documentation, here at least

```
Y = odeint(Oregonator,y0,t, tfirst=True)
```

And you need to equalize the indentation in the `Oregonator` function. 
Then you get an oscillating graph.

Also, increase the display resolution, 100 points in an interval with over 100 oscillations is much too few. As there are sharp peaks you want at least 20 points per oscillation, better more, thus

```
t = np.linspace(0, 10,5000)
```